# NodeJS Capture output of NODEJS Command and Display to express window

Tags: node.js, express

NOTE: I do not want to capture the output of a bash command, however a command like:

```
console.log(1)
```

And it just say 1 on my express server instead of logging it to the console

I am very very new to NodeJs but skilled in python

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.param('cmd')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I want if I do:

```
prtc://my.server?cmd=console.log(1)
```

That page will display 1.
How would I do this?

Comment: You shoudn't do this at all. Imagine someone writes some bad(dangerous) code knowing that your app will happily execute it. They could destroy(delete db, stop processes/services, etc.) your server if the code was evaluated on the server or if you evaluate it on the client(browser) they could for example read some other users data. Just DON'T do it.

Comment: I know they could like do bad stuff but it is on a vm on REPL.IT - I can remove dangerous node commands if I need or maybe make an api key but all that will happen is I will get my main.js deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it on my own with PHP.

For anyone who needs the code, run this on REPL.IT or HEROKU or of the like.

```
<?php
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$command = $_GET['cmd'];

if ($lang == 'sh') {
  System($command);
};
if ($lang == 'python3') {
  System('python3 -c "'.$command.'"');
};
if ($lang == 'python2') {
  System('python2 -c "'.$command.'"');
};
if ($lang == 'node14') {
$fp = fopen('cmds.js', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $command);

System('node cmds.js');
unlink('cmds.js');
};
?>
```